# How to restore a minimized window having only its handle

Tags: c#, winapi

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
IntPtr hWnd;
foreach (Process proc in procs)
{
    if ((hWnd = proc.MainWindowHandle) != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", proc.ProcessName, hWnd);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I restore minimized window having its handle (`hWnd` variable).

I would be grateful if you could also supply with some documentation of window handlers so I can see how to manipulate them.

Comment: Call [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx) via [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're in the same application domain, you'll have to use an unmanaged API to do this.

```
private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
private void restoreWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633549(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Got it working, but with [`SW_RESTORE = 9;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry about that, should have looked closer at your question.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx Has all of the commands

Comment: To make it work when window is not minimized but behind another window in foreground, I did a simple trick: explicitly called `SW_MINIMIZE`, and then `SW_RESTORE`. It forced window to minimize and then brought it to foreground. Correct me if there is a better way to approach such situation.

Comment: @stil: If the window [IsIconic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527.aspx), call `ShowWindowAsync` with `SW_RESTORE`. Otherwise, bring it to the top of the Z-order by calling [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx).